# Браузер пишет что MIME type гугловской капчи не тот

Tags: php, recaptcha, mime-type

Хочу прикрутить гугловскую капчу третьей версии, использую виджет himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget, но при рендере он мне в консоли браузера выдает следующее: "The resource from “[https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=тут_мой_ключ](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87)” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)." Я понимаю что MIME тип отличается от application/javascript.  Как поправить это правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась сама собой, видимо на момент обнаружения проблемы не прошел период регистрации капчи.